# How to remove "something ptr": when I render form with formset_factory?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

When I render the site at the end of each form appear the string "Human ptr:"... how can I delete it?
(Human is class where Player derives from)

---

I have a form made with modelformset_factory rendered like this:

---

team_area.html

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Area Squadra</h1>
  <form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ player_formset.management_form }}
    {% for player_form in player_formset %}
        {% for field in player_form %}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Aggiorna">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

---

And the view is managed by:

---

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from skeleton.models import Player
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import PlayerForm
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound


# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def team_area(request):
    if request.user.team != None:
        PlayerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Player, form=PlayerForm, extra=1, can_delete=True,)
        if request.method == "POST":
            player_formset = PlayerFormSet(
                request.POST,
                request.FILES,
                queryset=Player.objects.all().filter(team=request.user.team),)

            for player_form in player_formset:
                if player_form.is_valid():
                    player = player_form.save(commit=False)
                    player.team = request.user.team
                    #if player.first_name != '' and player.last_name != '':
                    #    player.save()

            if player_formset.is_valid():
                player_formset.save()
            return redirect('team_area:home')
        else:
            player_formset = PlayerFormSet(queryset=Player.objects.all().filter(team=request.user.team))
        return render(request, 'team_area/team_area.html', {'player_formset': player_formset})
    else:
        return render(request, 'team_area/empty_page.html')
```

---

base_layout.html

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ioniCup</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
      {% block header %}
        <ul>
          <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'team_area:home' %}">Area Squadre</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a></li>
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li>
              <form class="logout_link" action="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Logout</button>
              </form>
            </li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}">Signup</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
      {% endblock %}
    </header>

    <div class="content">
      {% block content %}
        <h1>Home</h1>
      {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <footer>
      {% block footer %}
      <h4>COPYRIGHT © 2018 IONICUP. TUTTI I DIRITTI RISERVATI.</h4>
      {% endblock %}
    </footer>


  </body>
</html>
```

I expect to remove Human ptr: possibly without css or javascript

Comment: Please post your base_layout.html

Comment: @art06 I just added it